# Adjusting table widths according to page layout in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking to automate a tedious part of my job with visual basic in Word. I work on long word documents and tables have to be certain widths (6.5 inches [or 468 points] in portrait orientation and 9 inches [or 648 points] in landscape). So far I have

```
Sub TableResize()

Dim oTbl As Table

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

        oTbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed

        With ActiveDocument.PageSetup

            oTbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints

            oTbl.PreferredWidth = 468

            oTbl.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    
    End With
    
    Next oTbl

End Sub
```

Which works great to set ALL tables to 6.5 inches and align them to the center, but this of course screws up the tables on pages that are landscape oriented. Can anyone help me to set the table widths according to the page layout?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    .AllowAutoFit = False
    .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    If .Range.Sections.First.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
      .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(6.5)
    Else
      .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(9)
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You beauty! That did it. I imagine I can use a similar format to adjust only unbordered tables to 6 inches with a 0.5 inch left indent?

Comment: You could - with just five more lines of code, though more code lines could be used to make it more efficient.

Comment: Sorry for asking this basic question: what is the difference between setting the `Width` and the `PreferredWidth` for a cell? I can't find an answer to this question.

Comment: For starters, Width doesn't work in the context in which it is being used in the code above...

Answer (score 0):

If you change your .PreferredWidthType to wdPreferredWidthPercent, its size will be proportional to the page width. You only need to change two lines of your code:

```
  oTbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
  oTbl.PreferredWidth = 468
```

Replace with following:

```
  oTbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent 
  oTbl.PreferredWidth = 50   ' Change with suitable value
```

However, instead of 50, you need to work out and change to the value that suits your requirement

Answer (score 0):

While you could test the width of each page and set the table accordingly, this is simpler:

```
Sub TableResize()
    Dim oTbl As Table
    
    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        With oTbl
            .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitFixed
            .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
            .PreferredWidth = 100
            .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        End With
    Next oTbl
End Sub
```

I also cleaned up your code a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with using wdPreferredWidthPercent is that when it is converted from 100%  to inches in table properties it ends up being 6.49" and 8.99", which isn't likely to fly at my company, as they need to be set in points at 6.5" and 9". I might be able to show them this and have them consider how much faster it is, just don't know if that will work.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can first test the width of each page, then set the table width in points.